# Scrape a list item to a Google Spreadsheet with the importXML function

Tags: xml, web-scraping, google-sheets, xpath

I'm trying to make a spreadsheet that automatically pulls some information of a bookstore website. Actually the only information that i need from the webpage is:

- Title
- Author
- Price
- ISBN or EAN (International Standard Book Number or International Article Number)

I'm trying to do this with the importxml function and for the title, author & price this works perfectly when i paste the Xpath link into the formula/function.

It also pulls the ISBN or EAN from the webpage but i think because the number is an HTML list object something goes wrong. As you can see in the screenshot it automatically puts the number on the next row in the spreadsheet.

[image: screenshot-google-spreadsheet-xml-xpath]

If anyone has a solution for this that would be more than welcome.

Link to the actual spreadsheet:

> > [Google Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15a8RtSoclyia0ZBhXJkrkjgg-4GtsokjP3vbMiMVIh0/edit?usp=sharing)

Greets

Pablo

Comment: Please edit your question and add the actual url, not an image.

Comment: Ok, so i added a link to the actual google spreadsheet. If that's what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap a `query` around it and off set the value by 1:

`=query(importxml(A5,"/html/body/div[8]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[2]/text()"),"offset 1",0)`

Locale settings may need this:

=query(importxml(A5;"/html/body/div[8]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[2]/text()");"offset 1";0)

Comment: It might be your file locale. Try the edited solution `;` in place of `,`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
=INDEX(IMPORTXML(A5;"/html/body/div[8]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[2]/text()");2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
=IMPORTXML(A5;"//ul[@class='c-list c-list--semantic']/li[./span[text()='Productcode (EAN):']]/text()[2]")
```

BTW, your other xpath expressions can also be truncated. For example, to get the price you can use

```
=IMPORTXML(A5;"//*[@id='productDetail']//span[@class='c-product__detail__price--largest']/text()")
```